# Minimize failing on a polynomial

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

Calling:

```
Minimize[{-0.4877 - 0.1190 r^2 - 0.1885 r^4 + 2.9703 z - 0.5531 z^2,
          0 <= z <= 3.5 ∧ 0 <= r <= 1.75}, {r, z}]
```

returns `{1.00051, {r -> 1.75, z -> 3.5}}`, when it's obvious that simply setting `r` and `z` to `0` yields `-0.4877`.

Is this an issue of numerical instability? Is there anything that can be done about it?

Comment: Seems like a failure of the default `"NelderMead"` method. If I change the `RandomSeed`, it works: `NMinimize[{-0.4877 - 0.1190 r^2 - 0.1885 r^4 + 2.9703 z - 0.5531 z^2, 0 <= z < 3.5, 0 <= r < 1.75}, {r, z}, Method -> {"NelderMead", RandomSeed -> 1}]`. Switching to `"DifferentialEvolution"` or `"SimulatedAnnealing"` gives the right answer, too.

Comment: @J.M. Also works with `DifferentialEvolution`. NelderMead can get stuck in local minima depending on how large the initial simplex is. Or in this case, gets stuck at the boundary condition.

Comment: If you have a polynomial, you can rationalize the system and use Minimize (not NMinimize):  `Minimize[Rationalize@{-0.4877 - 0.1190 r^2 - 0.1885 r^4 + 2.9703 z - 
    0.5531 z^2, 0 <= z <= 3.5 && 0 <= r <= 1.75}, {r, z}]`

Comment: `Minimize` uses exact methods and gets confused here due to the machine-precision values. Try `SetPrecision[Unevaluated[...], Infinity]`, which produces `{-(6041450097168177621/2305843009213693952), {r -> 7/4, z -> 0}}`.

Comment: (Yes, I deliberately used `NMinimize[]`, since `Minimize[]` switches to the use of `NMinimize[]` in the presence of inexact numbers. If you `Rationalize[]` your polynomial's coefficients, you might see something you'd prefer.)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Rationalizing did the trick for me!

Comment: @J.M. that's news to me. And pretty dirty, in my opinion, since `Minimize` is more like `Solve`. Handling this problem automatically by rationalizing the coefficients would seem to be far better than applying heuristic methods that are by no means guaranteed to succeed (indeed, which can quite readily fail for fairly trivial reasons).

Comment: @Oleksandr, I agree that [this behavior](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Minimize.html#148710633) is a rather dirty trick on *Mathematica*'s part, and I'd sure like to know why it was designed that way...

Comment: @J.M. would you mind posting an answer to that effect? This note is easy to miss (I missed it...) and the behavior is very surprising, so I think it's warranted to call attention to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [noted in the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Minimize.html#148710633), when given any input that contains inexact numbers, `Minimize[]` automagically switches to the use of `NMinimize[]`, which, as you might surmise from its name, uses approximate methods instead of exact ones. With this, the failure you see is due to the Nelder-Mead method, which is [the default method used by `NMinimize[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#10453).

If you're angling for exact solutions, then you certainly should be supplying exact input (GIGO). In that regard, `Rationalize[]` is a rather handy thing:

```
Minimize[{-0.4877 - 0.1190 r^2 - 0.1885 r^4 + 2.9703 z - 0.5531 z^2,
          0 <= z <= 3.5 ∧ 0 <= r <= 1.75} // Rationalize, {r, z}]
   {-6707357/2560000, {r -> 7/4, z -> 0}}
```

If one is fine with an approximate solution (which is often much easier to obtain), and the default settings are not up to snuff, then one way to angle for a possibly better answer from the built-in optimization methods is to change the `RandomSeed` option. To wit,

```
NMinimize[{-0.4877 - 0.1190 r^2 - 0.1885 r^4 + 2.9703 z - 0.5531 z^2, 
           0 <= z <= 3.5 ∧ 0 <= r <= 1.75}, {r, z},
          Method -> {Automatic, RandomSeed -> 1}] // Chop
   {-2.6200613281250007, {r -> 1.75, z -> 0}}
```

Another route is to change the default method. For instance,

```
NMinimize[{-0.4877 - 0.1190 r^2 - 0.1885 r^4 + 2.9703 z - 0.5531 z^2, 
           0 <= z <= 3.5 ∧ 0 <= r <= 1.75}, {r, z},
          Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"] // Chop
   {-2.6200613281250007, {r -> 1.75, z -> 0}}
```